# Route specific trafic trough vpn without split tunneling

Tags: vpn, split-tunneling

My goal is to gain access to a sambashare on my schools network (using a vpn), while not routing all other traffic trough the vpn. The school has disabled split tunneling. Is this possible? I'm using cisco vpn client.

Comment: Question about bypassing network security policies, and questions from end-users of a network, are both specifically off-topic.

Comment: I never meant to bypass network security policies. I am merely trying to get a smooth workflow, by not having to switch the vpn on and off all the time. If doing so creates any security leaks, then I hope someone would tell me - and more importantly, why?

Comment: You are an end-user of the network so you need to take this up with the administrators of the network. Questions from network users are specifically off-topic. Please see the Help Center for which types of questions are allowed, and which types are not allowed.

Comment: @wolfgervdp, that sounds like it should be a separate question. The answer is that it depends on the configuration/environment. When your computer is connected by VPN, it could be treated as any other computer that is protected behind deployed security. If your computer has access to local resources or the Internet, then it is exposed to those in return as well. That means your computer while treated as a protected resources is not protected like the other resources, which can make it a vulnerability allowing an attacker to bypass the deployed security.

Comment: @RonMaupin It seems that I have indeed taken this question to the wrong stackexchange community, for which I'm sorry.

Comment: @YLearn I disagree on being another question, since I asked whether this is possible. If not - without bypassing network security policies - the answer should be simply "no", preferably giving a reason why. But, meta-talk aside, thank you for your explanation.

Comment: @wolfgervdp, while it is a related question, it is a follow up in the comments, which is not how comments are intended to be used. It should really be posted as a separate question or edited into your current question for a community such as Stack Exchange. Since this question is deemed off topic, another question would be the better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cisco VPN Client will not allow you to alter/override tunnel policies. Should you manage to get around that, the tunnel will not carry traffic that doesn't match the tunnel policy.

You network admins have it setup the way they intend. If you require something different, you'll have to talk to them.

Answer (score -1):

You could do that by modifing your PC routing table, if split tunnel disabled VPN server will push default route to your PC 
So you need to do this:
1-add default route through you network with lower metric
2-add specific route to your school NFS server through the tunnel

Comment: This will not work with the Cisco VPN Client -- it will detect any tampering with the route table once the connection is established. (and even if you get past this, the software will not transport alien traffic.)